# Firebase multiple ValueEventListener Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In this days I'm trying to understand how Firebase real time database work, but I'm having some problems.
I have a Firebase database like this:

```
root/data1
root/data3
root/data3
.
.
root/dataN
```

My question is this. How can i implement a `ValueEventListener` on multiple child? (e.g. root/data3, root/data8, root/data9... it depends on the user).

Thanks for your support.

Comment: It depends on the user logged in? If so the "dataN" must be a variable and must be set according to the user. Use this variable to create the ValueEventListener.

Comment: It depends for example on what topics user want to be informed (ex userA wont to ve informed only on root/data1
 topic, userB on root/data30 topic and root/data98 topic,...)

Comment: So the Reaz Murshed answer is correct. For each user interaction (topic selection) you have to add a listener. If the you have to keep this selections after the user logout you have to persist a list containing all the topic ids the user has selected.

Answer (score 1):

You just change the reference of your firebase datapoint on user input. For example, you might consider changing the data point to data3, based on the `button3` click. Then implement your `onClickListener` like the following.

```
DatabaseReference dataPoint = databaseRef.child("root")

button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(View v) {
    ....
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dataPoint.child("data3").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Get the data associated with this node.
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The point is that root has a lot of child and each user decide to be informed about a few child. Ex user1 wont to be informed only on child root/child1, user2 on root/data40, root/data67,... the choose is dinamic on child and number